Identify the surface type using VBA in Catia
I want to find the surface type of each face in a dump surface so that I can extract faces other than cylindrical faces (i.e. fillets).
I'm trying to find the surface type but not able to get it in VBA and Catia too, is there any way?

You can use the TypeName of the face. (e.g. if TypeName(myFace) <> "CylindricalFace" then

Thanks @Shrotter
I tried to use it but the typename returns the value as "face" only, hence its extracting all faces.
its same for selection.Item(i).Type <>"CylindricalFace"
IS there anyother method to solve this issue

If TypeOf face is CylindricalFace then

You can use the search (use macro recorder to the the search string) to select all sub-surfaces and check the type of these faces.
Sub CATMain()

Dim oDoc As PartDocument
Dim oSel As Selection

Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oSel = oDoc.Selection

oSel.Search "Topology.CGMFace,all"

for i=1 to oSel.count2
    if TypeName(oSel.item2(i).value) <> "CylindricalFace" then
        'do something
    end if
next

End Sub


Thank you for your trying to help me.
but still the fillets return the typename as face only.
what should I do now

Can you post a picture of these surface? Or share a small example as igs or step?
